# Exploiting vulnerabilites in php's fopen

Tags: php, fopen, exploit

I am taking a cyber security class and for an assignment we have to exploit a specific php file and gain some sort of access to the server that it is hosted on.  I can set my own `$email` and $`password` variables as they are set with `$_POST`.  I believe the only piece of code I can exploit is this.

```
$email = $_POST['email']
$password = $_POST['password']
....    
$accountfile = "./acounts/" . $email

if(!file_exists($accountfile)){
  diefooter("unknown email address or password")
}
$fh = fopen($accountfile, "r")
if(!$fh){
  diefooter("Cannot open file $accountfile.");
}
$last = fgets($fh);
$first = fgets($fh);
$pass = fgets($fh);

if(strcmp($pass,$password)!=0){
  diefooter("wrong email or password.")
}
```

I know that there are vulnerabilities built into the fopen() function and that I can gain access to the shell with the correct input.

```
filePath = "/var/ctf/music-copyright/html/cgi-bin/login.php"
shellKode = "exploit@gmail.com\0;echo shell_exec("+'"cat '+filePath+'");'
# payload = {'email':shellKode, 'password':'test'}
testPayload = {'email':'exploit@gmail.com','password':'a'}
r = requests.post(url, data = testPayload)
print(r.text)
```

I can enter an email into the system but the format is verified before saving.  At this point I'm a little lost and not sure what else I can be doing.
`fopen()` is the only function in the file I think that can be exploited and I can't think of another place where an exploit may be.

Comment: hmm i do realize this seems like i am asking how to hack is there a way i can convince you / the other people viewing this.  I am showing the php code so that should be a bit of give away that i already have access to the system

Comment: Can you add more code under $fh = fopen($accountfile, "r") ? That would be required to know how to exploit fopen() in this particular case. Post more code before and after the exploitable bit. I think this is an interesting puzzle.

Comment: Just did! not sure if it will help or not.

Comment: Yes, that just told us how to exploit it.

Comment: Can you register an account?  If email ends in `.php` then you can write arbitrary PHP code to the file (via password?) and then it looks like that accounts directory is web accessible, so you can call it remotely to run the code.

Comment: Just checked and you can.  a@gmail.php was successfully created

Comment: Then see if you can access `vmhost/accounts/a@gmail.php` - if so, set your password to something like `<?php eval($_POST['code']); ?>` and then make a post request to the a@gmail.php file with the POST variable code containing arbitrary code which will run on the sever.  You can then do anything you want, write new files, look at stuff on the filesystem etc.

Comment: @drew010: I think you got it. I'll let you write the correct answer :-)

Comment: Thanks guys ill post the result i used by tomorrow hopefully.

Comment: @WadihM. Thanks Wadih, I upvoted yours too.  Hard to tell with only being able to see this little bit of code but good efforts either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think they're referring to the CRLF vulnerability.

In your sample exploit code, you're passing some php code, but that's not what you would do.

The goal is to make `fopen` open a file from the internet. If the `$email` variable contains two strings separated by a CRLF, you can have `fopen()` visit an external website there where it's not supposed to.

All depending on what happens with the `$fh` file descriptor after, it will determine how you will take advantage of that.

Here's a link I found on that vulnerability: http://www.securiteam.com/unixfocus/5OP0C0A8AC.html

**EDIT after you posted more code**:

We're starting with that you can force `$password` to the value you want.

So the name of the game is forcing `$pass` to the value you want, such that `strcmp` returns `true`, and you get logged in without knowing any password.

`$pass` is controlled in that last statement `$pass = fgets($fh)`

And if you use the CRLF vulnerability to point fopen to open a URL that you host, e.g. http://your.ip.address/your-file, and inside that file, you set the same data as you set in `$password`. And that should allow you to login without registration.

But there are some weird things in the code, e.g. :

```
$last = fgets($fh);
$first = fgets($fh);
$pass = fgets($fh);
```

Seems like the code might not be complete, because here the values of `$last`, `$first` and `$pass` will always all be the same which makes no sense. That would be one vector to consider.

**Possibility #2 - File traversal**:

Using `../` inside your `$email` variable, you will be able to access a different file in `fopen` that it outside the `acounts/` folder.

If you run:

```
<?php
$fh = fopen("acounts/../../test.sh","r");
?>
```

It evaluates successfully and looks for two folders up for the contents of test.sh. So you can probe the contents of the file system via the `$email` variable. Then the name of the game is finding a standard file which you know the contents for, feed it in `$password`, and you can login the system without registration.

**Possibility #3 - Register an email address ending with .php**:

As mentioned by drew010, assuming you are allowed to register a custom account, then by registering an `$email` ending in `.php`, and putting `eval()` php code inside `$password` when registering your account, that will create a backdoor file inside `acounts/` named after your `$email` that you can access via the web.

Comment: The file passed to `fopen` is prepended with `./accounts` so it will not use the remote HTTP fopen wrapper.  The above does not seem to be the attack vector for this case.

Comment: The code before just saves email and password via  and then checks to make sure they are not empty, sets a cookie and thats about it.  I agree that i looks like there is no point for the multiple $last $first and $pass variable but thats how its coded.

Answer (score 4):

Since the file it opens to store user data is referenced as `$accountfile = "./acounts/" . $email` it looks like one possible attack vector would be to try to register an account using an email address like `something@domain.php` (or just `username.php` depending on whether there's proper validation).

Since it writes (presumably unhashed?) your password to that file, you can set your password to something evil (e.g. `<?php eval($_REQUEST['x'] ?>`).

Then, see if you can access `http://thesite/accounts/something@domain.php?x=echo 'hi';` and see if 'hi' is printed out to the browser.

If that's the case, then have fun with `$_REQUEST['x']` and get it to do things like write arbitrary files to the system (a webshell) or open and read other files and print their contents.